# python filter calculated values from large lists to create multiple smaller lists

Tags: python, list, filter, list-comprehension

I want to find an optimal method to process very large ordered lists of integers eg.

```
biglist = [45, 34, 2, 78, 7, 9, 10, 33, 78, 51, 99, 24, 88, ... N] where N > 1m
```

to create multiple small lists of fixed length S (~=200) by reading each biglist element, apply different operations on the element, and if meets a conditional criteria add the element or a value to each small list until S is reached eg.

```
x_smallist = []
y_smallist = []
z_smallist = []
count = 0
for i in biglist:
    b = i / 5
    a = b * 2
    c = a^3 + b
    if b > 7 and b < 69:
        x_smallist.append(i)
        y_smallist.append(a)
        z_smallist.append(b)
        count += 1
    if count > S:
        break
```

The example and function is for illustration only. As biglist is large and each element is read and operated on until S is reached, and the process is repeated thousands of times, I want to avoid the for-loop. How can this be achieved with a list comprehension (or map or filter)?

Comment: If you are doing this much processing for each element, a) you won't be able to express it in a list comprehension, and b) the time-savings of the list comprehension will be dwarfed by the real work you have to do anyway.

Comment: This is best done as a `for` loop. list comprehensions and `filter` are for when you don't need intermediate variables like `a`, `b`, and `count` are here. My only possible suggestion to make it faster is have a single list that you append tuples to: `smallist.append((i, a, b))`.

Comment: seems to be trivial to prefilter the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should do what you want, this works by having a generator yield a tuple with a new element for each list, and then using zip to create the three lists you want.  An iterator for `biglist` is created at the beginning so that each time through the loop you will pick up where you left off, and `islice` is used so that the generator stops at `S` elements.

```
itr = iter(biglist)
while True:
    lists = itertools.islice(((i, i/5*2, i/5) for i in itr if 7 < i/5 < 69), S)
    x_smallist, y_smallist, z_smallist = zip(*lists)
    if len(x_smallist) == 0:
        break       # reached the end of biglist
    # do stuff with your small lists
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `biglist` really have to be a list?  If you can create them with a generator, you can save the memory, and perhaps save some time.

Comment: biglist could be any appropriate data structure but the elements are pre-calculated and ordered.

Answer (score 0):

```
S = 200
import itertools
biglist = itertools.islice(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: 7 < x/5 < 69, biglist),S)
```

or if you want multiple chunks just apply `ifilter` and then loop on the result.